# What abilities does Kang the Conqueror’s armor have?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-and-the-wasp-quantumania

During the events of *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania*, while trapped in the *Quantum Realm* and working with Kang to fix his ship’s power source, Janet Van Dyne

> gets a glimpse of his mind and decides to destroy his ship's power source.

Ultimately she manages to get out and while talking to her family, she says that she left him his armor that

> he used to build and oppress whole civilizations.

The question is what are his armor's abilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official [Marvel](https://www.marvel.com/characters/kang/in-comics) website reads -

> Kang’s full-body armor (composed of an unidentified future metal) enables him to lift 5 tons, and can project a gravito-electromagnetic force field around him that is extendable up to 20 feet and can even shield him from a direct nuclear strike. The suit has its own self-contained atmosphere, food supply and waste disposal system. Its weapons include anti-graviton particle projectors in his gauntlets, rendering weightless objects up to 2.2 tons; concussive force blasters equivalent to up to several thousand pounds of TNT; circuitry accessing his ship’s time machine (or other such resources), allowing him an “automatic recall” of a few seconds, as well as enabling him to peer into various timelines; and various other weapons that are regularly updated. Kang formerly used technology that transferred his mind into an alternate body upon the point of death.